# How do I retrieve the values of checkboxes when the Id values are dynamically generated

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, checkbox

I am dynamically naming a set of checkboxes based on certain files names (user is selecting file to include for some processing).

Is there a way I can retrieve the files names or do I need to save them to a session object of some sort and then use the retrieved values (from the session object) to retrieve the values of the checkboxes.

In short what I really want is to know which checkboxes have been clicked and which file names they correspond to, any solution will be fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use unique `id`, but same `name`. Then you will be able to use either `getParameterValues(name)`, or `getParameterMap()` of `ServletRequest`. Remember, you will only get what is selected.

Comment: This was my immediate response, too.  You beat me to it.

Comment: Indeed just give them all the same `name` and access them using `getParameterValues()`. There's no need for the brace notation as some PHP'er noticed here by the way.

Comment: In the end I refactored the code and used the reParameterValues() method to get a list of the selected checkboxes. That's all I need for the rest of the code to work, so all is good. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing all this server side or using java-script client side?

If it's all server side, why not prepend checkbox on the name when you dynamically name them:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_someRandomeName" value="something" />
```

You can then loop the posted variables and see if the name starts with "checkbox":

```
ParameterMap paramMap = request.getParameterMap();
// Loop through the list of parameters.
Iterator y = paramMap.keySet().iterator();
while (y.hasNext()) {
  String name = (String) y.next();  
  if name.startswith("checkbox"){
    // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting idea, but the above technique as Vinegar has suggested.

Comment: Ahh, makes perfect sense. I assumed you were using the name and the value properties to both store variable information, so therefore you needed to keep your naming structure intact.

Answer (score 0):

What does your HTML look like?  I'd expect checkboxes like:

```
<li><input id='0001' type='checkbox' name="files[]" value="file1"/>/xyz/file1</li>
<li><input id='0002' type='checkbox' name="files[]" value="file2"/>/xyz/file2</li>
<li><input id='0003' type='checkbox' name="files[]" value="file3"/>/xyz/file3</li>
<li><input id='0004' type='checkbox' name="files[]" value="file4"/>/xyz/file4</li>
```

The *name* will be associated with any values checked on submit.  Here, I used *files[]* because that's required by PHP, I haven't done this in servlets.